# Rails 4, Ruby 2.0: Get PG Error when trying to get all records having a specified value in joined table

Tags: ruby, join, scope, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

Given the following two classes:

```
class VacationRequestDay < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :vacation_request, :inverse_of => :vacation_request_days,
                                :class_name => "VacationRequest",
                                :foreign_key => "vacation_request_id"

  #attributes: :id, :vacation_request_id, :date, :fullday

end


class VacationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :vacation_request_days, dependent: :destroy,
                                   inverse_of: :vacation_request
  #attributes: :id, state, :user

end
```

I want to receive all VacationRequestDays where `vacation_request_day.vacation_request.state == :pending`

I tried the following (in VacationRequestDay class):

```
    scope :by_state, lambda { |state| joins(:vacation_request).where('vacation_request.state = ?', state) }

which results in the following Postgres error: 

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "vacation_request"
       LINE 1: ...cation_request_days"."vacation_request_id" WHERE (vacation_r...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT "vacation_request_days".* FROM "vacation_request_days" INNER JOIN "vacation_requests" ON "vacation_requests"."id" = "vacation_request_days"."vacation_request_id" WHERE (vacation_request.state = 'pending')
```

Second I tried:

```
def self.by_state(state)
    VacationRequestDay.joins(:vacation_request)
                      .where(:vacation_request => { :state => state })
  end
```

This results in the same error. Has anyone an idea how to fix it? 
As you can see I tried already the hints from
[rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448983/rails-3-retrieve-all-child-records-where-parent-model-attribute-equals-search-k)

Comment: Found the error. The correct scope is 

    scope :by_state, lambda { |state| joins(:vacation_request).where('state = ?', state) }

so I had to leave out the model in the inner join.

Cheers